# Game engine for C++ developer

Tags: library, c++, game-development

I've been programming in C/C++ for quite some time (Mostly Microcontroller and Qt). And i've been looking for a game engine that i can use since i want to program isometric and 2d games. However most of the engines i've found online(Godot, Unity, ...) are very GUI intensive and i want to work in a development environment not in some "scene-graph-click-thing" and stick to "simple" programming.

I've looked into SDL and OpenGL but OpenGL is just to time consuming (SDL felt better).

So my question is: 
Can you recommend me a (2d/isometric) game engine that is somewhat simplistic but still offers a good amount of convenience?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org). It has few forks and one of them is C++.

Comment: The now mature [cocos2d-x](https://www.cocos2d-x.org) project is actually a good option for more code-centric isometric 2D game development.